# MapKit iPhone Development - Adding Annotations to a Map - iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, mapkit

I would like to create annotations on a Map like this:
[image: img]

If you click on the blue arrow a menu should open.
In the menu should be two menu points.
First a Telephone number (if I click on the number the iphone dial/call this number) and second a "Directions to here".

At the moment I run on this code

```
MKCoordinateRegion region4 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region4.center.latitude = 48.13479 ;
region4.center.longitude = 11.582111;
region4.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region4.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

DisplayMap *ann4 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann4.title = @"The Title!";
ann4.subtitle = @"The Subtitle!"; 
ann4.coordinate = region4.center; 
[mapView addAnnotation:ann4];
```

How do I show blue-arrow as shown in the image? Can you please suggest me on this..

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: how i get this little blue arrow?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a `UIButton` of type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` in the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` of your `MKAnnotationView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MKAnnotationView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and "Managing Callout Views" specifically.